# make custom range v3 view pipeable

Tags: c++, range-v3

I'm trying to implement masked range views with range v3. Somehow I ended up in the situation where my implementation of

```
ranges::view::masker(datarange, mask)
```

works, but the piped version

```
ranges::view::all(datarange) | ranges::view::masker(mask)
```

doesn't, although withing the `operators` of the internal structures, the masks arrive correctly. (I put my implementation of `masker` into the `ranges::view` namespace, although it is not part of range v3).

My test program is relatively trivial, create some widgets and a meaningless mask

```
class Widget
{
private:
  int   m_int{0};

public:
  Widget() {}
  Widget( int i ) : m_int( i ) {}
  int   the_int() const { return m_int; }
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& str, const Widget& obj )
{
  str << '\t' << obj.the_int();
  return str;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Widget> widgets;
  std::vector<bool>   mask;

  for ( auto i : ranges::view::indices( 24 ) ) {
    widgets.emplace_back( i );
    mask.push_back( i % 3 != 1 );
  }

  std::cout << "wrapped" << std::endl;
  for ( auto& el : ranges::view::masker( widgets, mask ) ) {
    std::cout << el << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::cout << "piped" << std::endl;
  for ( auto& el : ranges::view::all( widgets ) | ranges::view::masker( mask ) ) {
    std::cout << el << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Ignoring namespaces and debug printout the `masker` just zips the data range and the mask together, filters on the mask and returns the widgets as view:

```
        struct mask_fn
        {
            template<typename Rng, typename Msk>
            auto operator()(Rng&& rng, Msk&& msk) const
            {
                CONCEPT_ASSERT(Range<Rng>());
                CONCEPT_ASSERT(Range<Msk>());

                return ranges::view::zip(std::forward<Rng>(rng),
                                         std::forward<Msk>(msk)) |
                       ranges::view::filter([](auto&& range_item) -> bool {

                           return range_item.second;
                       }) |
                       ranges::view::transform(
                           [](auto&& range_item) -> decltype(auto) {
                               return range_item.first;
                           });
            }                  
            template<typename Msk>
            auto operator()(Msk&& msk) const -> decltype(
                make_pipeable(std::bind(*this, std::placeholders::_1,
                                        protect(std::forward<Msk>(msk)))))
            {   
                CONCEPT_ASSERT(Range<Msk>());
                return make_pipeable(
                    std::bind(*this,
                              std::placeholders::_1,
                              protect(std::forward<Msk>(msk))));
            }                 
        };                    

        RANGES_INLINE_VARIABLE(mask_fn, masker)
```

The above program is intended to print out the same resulting range twice, yet I only get:

```
wrapped
    0
    2
    3
    5
    6
    8
    9
    11
    12
    14
    15
    17
    18
    20
    21
    23


piped
```

So while using `auto operator()(Rng&& rng, Msk&& msk) const` the right widgets are looped over, the version with `auto operator()(Msk&& msk) const` does not return anything.

I tried adding some debug printout to the former (because it gets ultimately called by the latter) and observe that the mask arrives correctly.

```
        struct mask_fn
        {
            template<typename Rng, typename Msk>
            auto operator()(Rng&& rng, Msk&& msk) const
            {
                CONCEPT_ASSERT(Range<Rng>());
                CONCEPT_ASSERT(Range<Msk>());
                for(auto t :
                    ranges::view::zip(rng, msk) |
                        ranges::view::filter([](auto&& range_item) ->
                        bool {
                            return range_item.second;
                        }) |
                        ranges::view::transform(
                            [](auto&& range_item) -> decltype(auto) {
                                return range_item.first;
                            }))
                    std::cout << "w: " << t << std::endl;
                return ranges::view::zip(std::forward<Rng>(rng),
                                         std::forward<Msk>(msk)) |
                       ranges::view::filter([](auto&& range_item) -> bool {
                           std::cout << "checking widget "
                                     << range_item.first << std::endl;
                           std::cout << "returning " << range_item.second
                                     << std::endl;
                           return range_item.second;
                       }) |
                       ranges::view::transform(
                           [](auto&& range_item) -> decltype(auto) {

                               return range_item.first;
                           });
            }
            template<typename Msk>
            auto operator()(Msk&& msk) const -> decltype(
                make_pipeable(std::bind(*this, std::placeholders::_1,
                                        protect(std::forward<Msk>(msk)))))
            {
                CONCEPT_ASSERT(Range<Msk>());
                return make_pipeable(
                    std::bind(*this,
                              std::placeholders::_1,
                              protect(std::forward<Msk>(msk))));
            }
        };

        RANGES_INLINE_VARIABLE(mask_fn, masker)
```

(cutting the output a bit) one can see that using the supposed return range within `operator()` I loop over the correct widgets, but the printout from within the lambdas in the return line shows "false" flags for all items.

```
wrapped
w:  0
w:  2
w:  3
w:  5
<snap>
w:  20
w:  21
w:  23
checking widget     0
returning 1
    0
checking widget     1
returning 0
checking widget     2
returning 1
    2
checking widget     3
returning 1
    3
<snap>
checking widget     22
returning 0
checking widget     23
returning 1
    23


piped
w:  0
w:  2
w:  3
w:  5
<snap>
w:  20
w:  21
w:  23
checking widget     0
returning 0
checking widget     1
returning 0
checking widget     2
returning 0
checking widget     3
returning 0
<snap>
checking widget     22
returning 0
checking widget     23
```

My best guess at the moment is that I messed up the `protect`, `std::forward`, `&&`, or `std::move` somewhere, though I tried to stick as close as possible to `filter.hpp` (since I thought I had understood it reasonably well) and also tried some random adding/removing of ampersands and forwards without success.

Any suggestion how to fix this? (And ideally explanation of what's going on, along?).

Thanks in advance.

footnotes: I'm at the moment not concerned about c++11 compatibility.

EDIT:

I pushed the mess to [github](https://github.com/pseyfert/range_v3_playground/tree/ed62595a157c8b26f71aea90edb9d989bbf326ec).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::bind` is weird. If you pass a `bind_expression` - the result of a call to `std::bind` - to `std::bind`, it produces an expression tree that is evaluated from the "leaves" down. For example:

```
auto f = [](int i, int j){ return i * j; };
auto g = [](int i) { return i + 1; };
auto b = std::bind(f, std::bind(g, std::placeholders::_1), std::placeholders::_2);
std::cout << b(0, 3) << '\n'; // prints 3
```

The call `b(0, 3)` here is equivalent to `f(g(0), 3)`.

`protect` is a range-v3 utility used to capture function objects inside the `bind` object that prevents `std::bind` from engaging this weirdness if those function objects happen to be `bind_expression`s. For non-`bind_expressions`, `protect` has "capture rvalues by value and lvalues by reference" behavior (most things in range-v3 assume that the caller guarantees lifetime of lvalues but that rvalues may "disappear" before needed and therefore must be stored).

Unfortunately, you use `protect` with a `Range` in your "partial application" overload:

```
template<typename Msk>
auto operator()(Msk&& msk) const -> decltype(
    make_pipeable(std::bind(*this, std::placeholders::_1,
                            protect(std::forward<Msk>(msk)))))
{   
    CONCEPT_ASSERT(Range<Msk>());
    return make_pipeable(
        std::bind(*this,
                  std::placeholders::_1,
                  protect(std::forward<Msk>(msk))));
}
```

`std::bind` has a different design from range-v3: it stores copies of whatever you pass inside the returned `bind_expression` and passes lvalues denoting those stored objects to the wrapped function upon invocation. The end effect is that your overload returns a `bind_expression` wrapped in a `make_pipeable` that holds a copy of the `vector` the caller passed in.

When the test program "pipes" in another range, the `make_pipeable` invokes your other overload with that range and an lvalue denoting the `vector` copy stored inside the bind expression. You pass that lvalue to `view::zip` which (as described above) assumes that its caller will guarantee that lvalue will remain alive as long as the `zip_view` it produces. This is of course not the case: The `make_pipeable` temporary - including the `vector` stored inside the `bind_expression` it contains - are destroyed after evaluating the initializer in the range-for statement in the test program. When the range-for tries to access that dead `vector`, UB occurs which manifests in this case as an empty range.

The fix is to not use `protect` in your "partial application" overload, but to instead pass an `all_view` of the range to `std::bind`:

```
template<typename Msk>
auto operator()(Msk&& msk) const -> decltype(
    make_pipeable(std::bind(*this, std::placeholders::_1,
                            ranges::view::all(std::forward<Msk>(msk)))))
{   
    CONCEPT_ASSERT(Range<Msk>());
    return make_pipeable(
        std::bind(*this,
                  std::placeholders::_1,
                  ranges::view::all(std::forward<Msk>(msk))));
}
```

(Admittedly, it would be nice if `protect` would guard against this error by refusing to accept `Range`s.)

Answer (score 0):

After more trying around, we figured out that the `std::bind` should receive a `std::ref` to the mask.

```
            return make_pipeable(
                std::bind(*this,
                          std::placeholders::_1,
                          std::ref(msk));
```

If not, then - so my understanding - the `masker` would outlive a temporary copy of the `msk`.

Comment: FYI, this won't work when someone passes an rvalue `View` to your "partial application" overload: You'll return a `bind_expression` that stores a `reference_wrapper` to that (possibly temporary) `View` object.